# Page jumps on loading

Tags: css, html, pagespeed

For some reason my page jumps on loading. It appears it's CSS that's slowing things down. How do I identify what is causing this so I can fix it?

https://guarded-ridge-84478.herokuapp.com/

The site is built on Keystone.js. In HTML the page loads fine.

Comment: You can't fix it without the code. Where is the code?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the URL

Comment: Nope, not URL, but the relevant code, please.

Comment: @nicael could you have a look at the URL and then tell me which part of the code you'd like to see? This happens on all the pages

Comment: It doesn't jump for me.

Comment: Definitely a loading issue. Happens on 3 different devices.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the following article on how to best help us help you. I am able to repro your problem but there's a lot of code to slog through. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position of the top div to fixed.